# Debugging PHP with VIM using Quickfix

Tags: php, vim

I followed some tutorials to debug and lint php code through VIM.

Here is my piece of PHP code to test

```
<?php echo "test" echo "test2";?>
```

The following code worked for me:

```
:autocmd FileType php noremap <C-L> :!$HOME/bin/php -l %<CR>
```

It tells me that there is a syntax error.
Problem is that i want to use the quickfix console. So, here is the code:

```
set makeprg="php -l %"
nmap <F9>:make<ENTER>:copen<ENTER><CTRL>L
```

F9 opens the quickfix window, but detects no syntax error. (I save my php document before with :w)

Thanks for your time !

Comment: What happens if you simply call `:make` and then use `:copen`?

Comment: @Xavier T. : It works great and there is no bug like I mentionned in my comment on the Peter Rincker's answer. Now, question is, why your solution doesn"t work with key mapping... Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem i see is using `"` w/ `:set`. I suggest the following:

```
:set makeprg=php\ -ln\ %
:set errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l
nnmap <f9> :sil! make<cr>:cwindow<cr>
```

To make this a bit more friendly with other file types I suggest you put the following in your ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim and making sure you use `:setlocal` and your mappings have `<buffer>` attribute like this:

```
:setlocal makeprg=php\ -ln\ %
:setlocal errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l
nnmap <buffer> <f9> :sil! make<cr>:cwindow<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, It looks like to work but I think there is a little bug (maybe with my vimrc)... Some screenshots worth more than words: [Before](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/capture1yb.png/)   and [After](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/37/capture2ld.png/)

Comment: I tried your snippets on a fresh Ubuntu install and i have the same display bug. A part of the source code is erased when i trigger F9

Comment: @Matthieu: I do not completely understand what the bug is. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Matthieu: this is just a guess of what your bug is, try setting errorformat with `:set errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l,%-GErrors\ parsing\ %f,%-G`

Comment: Have you seen the pictures behind the links Before and After on my first comment ? Thing is that when i trigger F9, a part of my code is erased (Not in quickfix window but in my source code). Not erased from the file, because when i reopen it, nothing has changed. It looks like a "display" bug. Very weird...

Comment: @Matthieu: do you have `lazyredraw` set? maybe `nnmap <f9> :sil! make<cr>:cwindow<cr>:redraw!<cr>` would fix that.